# Angular Meteor - Publish Single Document, Watch for Changes in Mongo and Change Accordingly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I need to find a way to 'watch' a random document from my database, currently how I'm trying to go about this is by using the following to publish:

```
// Generate a random ID from our documents
function randomId() {

    // Count total documents, then generate a random index
    var count = Documents.find().count();
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);

    // Get our random document
    var document =  Documents.findOne({}, {
        skip: random
    });

    // Return the Document ID
    return document._id;

}


// Publish a random document
Meteor.publish("randomDocument", function(random) {

    var documentId = randomDocumentId();
    return Documents.find({
        _id : documentId,
    })

})
```

This works fine, the problem comes in the UI when I decide I want to vote on it. I will press the vote button, but the counter won't increase or decrease on the UI. Currently I'm loading the subscription into $scope using the following code:

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('randomDocument', Random.fraction()).then(function(subHandle) {    

    // Load latest random document into scope
    var documents = $meteor.collection(Documents)
    $scope.document = documents[documents.length-1]

})
```

In the UI I'm using the following to display the yes votes:

```
span.details-pane-yes {{ document.votes }}
```

This is the method I'm calling to increment the votes:

```
Documents.update(documentId, {
  $inc: {
    votes: 1
  }
});
```

Whenever this is called, the UI doesn't update to reflect it. It does show in the database when I query it from my terminal though.

What I need is for the counter to update when any user votes on the document, and I just can't seem to get it working regardless of what I try. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!